# Pandas match on multiple columns and get matching values as a single new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with about 5 columns. The value I am looking to match could be present in either of the last 3 columns.

```
Key   |  col1   |  col2  |  col3 |  col4
----------------------------------------
1        abc       21        22      23
2        cde       22        21      20
3        fgh       20        22      23
4        lmn       20        22      21
```

I am filtering on value `21` on any of the last three columns as follows:

`df1 = df[(df['col2']=='21') | (df['col3']=='21') | (df['col4']=='21')]`

which gives me

```
Key   |  col1   |  col2  |  col3 |  col4
----------------------------------------
1        abc       21        22      23
2        cde       22        21      20
4        lmn       20        22      21
```

Using this new df1 I want to get this

```
Key   |  col1   |  newCol
-------------------------
1        abc       21      
2        cde       21      
4        lmn       21
```

Basically any of the matched column as the new column value. How do I do this using pandas? I appreciate the help. So I was thinking may be I should filter and map it to the new column at the same time but I don't know how?

Comment: From the second dataframe, how would you know which value you've filtered for? In this case it could have been either 21 or 22.

Comment: If you know what value you're matching on, why can't you create the new column as this value? Or are you asking to pull out the common values that exist in the 3 resulting columns (without knowing that it's '21')?

Comment: Right I don't know which one. So I was thinking may be I should filter and map it to the new column at the same time but I don't know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'abc', 21, 22, 23],
                   [2, 'cde', 22, 21, 20],
                   [3, 'fgh', 20, 22, 23],
                   [4, 'lmn', 20, 22, 21]],
                  columns=['Key', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])

df2 = df[np.logical_or.reduce([df[col] == 21 for col in ['col2', 'col3', 'col4']])]\
        .assign(newCol=21)\
        .drop(['col2', 'col3', 'col4'], 1)

#    Key col1  newCol
# 0    1  abc      21
# 1    2  cde      21
# 3    4  lmn      21
```

**Explanation**

- Store integers as integers rather than strings.
- `np.logical_or.reduce` applies your `|` condition across a list comprehension.
- `assign` creates a new column with the filter value.
- `drop` removes unwanted columns, `axis=1` refers to columns.

Comment: Both of these works but I can only accept one. Accepting this for the explanation. I will upvote the other answer from @Zero. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
In [722]: df.loc[df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']].eq(21).any(1), 
                 ['Key', 'col1']].assign(newcol=21)
Out[722]:
   Key col1  newcol
0    1  abc      21
1    2  cde      21
3    4  lmn      21
```

---

Details

Equality check `eq` on necessary `['col2', 'col3', 'col4']` columns

```
In [724]: df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']].eq(21)
Out[724]:
    col2   col3   col4
0   True  False  False
1  False   True  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False   True
```

`any` would return whether any element is True in the row

```
In [725]: df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']].eq(21).any(1)
Out[725]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Use `.loc` to subset the matched rows and necessary `['Key', 'col1']` columns.

```
In [726]: df.loc[df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4']].eq(21).any(1), ['Key', 'col1']]
Out[726]:
   Key col1
0    1  abc
1    2  cde
3    4  lmn
```

And, `.assign(newcol=21)` creates a `newcol` column set to `21`

Comment: imho -  this is definitely the best answer here - if it had more explanation though - that'd be great :)

Answer (score 0):

As jpp pointed out, you have 2 possibilities here: both 21 and 22 are common across all 3 columns. Assuming you don't know which one you're really looking for, what you can do is to use `set()` to isolate the unique values for each column, then use `set.intersection()` to find the commonalities:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'col1':'a', 'col2':21, 'col3':22, 'col4':23},
                   {'col1':'b', 'col2':22, 'col3':21, 'col4':20},
                   {'col1':'c', 'col2':20, 'col3':22, 'col4':21},
                   {'col1':'d', 'col2':21, 'col3':21, 'col4':22}])

s1 = set(df['col2'].values)
s2 = set(df['col3'].values)
s3 = set(df['col4'].values)

df['new_col'] = str(s1.intersection(s2, s3))
df

col1    col2    col3    col4    new_col
   a    21      22      23      {21, 22}
   b    22      21      20      {21, 22}
   c    20      22      21      {21, 22}
   d    21      21      22      {21, 22}
```